# Selecting a tripod for use with very long focal lengths

Tags: tripod, telephoto

I have been playing around with very long focal lengths using a Kenko 3x teleconverter. I have had problems getting sharp pictures and I think camera shake is a big part of that.

Given that I am planing to get a tripod to lock things down.

What should I look for in a tripod in this context?
I am currently using the sigma 100-300 f4 and a canon 5d mark ii but am also considering getting a 150-600mm zoom and the MTO-1000 mirror lens so any tripod I get I want to work with those.

I have heard that a heavy tripod is advisable in this context, is that correct and if so how heavy is heavy?

Looking around the web I found the [Genesis A3](http://www.genesisgear.pl/en/kits/75-genesis-a3-kit-en) tripod that looked promising, am I on the right track with this?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is shake rather than just the issues inevitably introduced by a 3x TC? For example, do the problems go away if you use the TC on a high quality wide-to-normal prime?

Comment: I sadly do not have any good lens to try that with. The best candidate is the 50mm 1.8 ii but as I get better results in good light or high iso I think shake is a big part of it, currently I do not own any tripod so handholding a 900mm lens or bracing against a railing is chalanging. That said, I do not expect miracles and am avare that the teleconverter will magnify any softness in the lenses used a lot.

Comment: What do you intend to shoot primarily? Do you need to be mobile and able to set up anywhere? Do you need to be able to quickly set up, or is a heavier studier tripod acceptable? Or are you always shooting from your backyard?

Comment: @scottbb I do not know, I expect that I will cary it a bit sometimes but, maybe half an hour from the car, but I do not expect going hiking with it. I’m not that weight consious but that depends, what is heavy in this context? 3kg maybe ok, 10kg, not so much.

Comment: Related: [What support system do I use to keep a telephoto lens stable?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/26468)

Comment: "camera shake"... what are you taking pictures of & at what kind of shutter speeds. For instance, a tree at 0.5s is going to have moved a long way in that time - the leaves, that is ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin that varies, but for the sake of the question assume two subjects, the moon and urban landskapes such as buildings along an empty street. I have used shutter speeds in the 2s to 1/200s range. (I know that camera shake is only part of the problem but one thing at a time, handholding 900mm at 1/40s is problematic.)

Comment: @lijat At effectively 900mm, pretty much any Tv longer than about 1/500 is going to show motion blur due to the Moon's movement relative to the Earth's surface, even if the camera is completely stable.

Comment: Related: [What properties should I look for to judge tripod quality?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/18802/15871) and [What support system do I use to keep a telephoto lens stable?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/26468/15871) and [What tripod heads are ideal to mount a large telephoto or supertelephoto lens on a tripod?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/30640/15871) and [What should one consider when choosing a style of tripod head?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/778/15871)

Comment: Also: [When are special long lens techniques necessary for sharp wildlife photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/85735/15871)
and [The Purpose of the Length of a Tripod Plate](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/77348/15871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should I look for in a tripod in this context? I am currently using the sigma 100-300 f4 and a canon 5d mark ii but am also considering getting a 150-600mm zoom and the MTO-1000 mirror lens so any tripod I get I want to work with those.

Long focal lengths require good technique. And part of that technique is proper tripod selection, and proper use of the tripod. A primary stabilizer of tripods is **mass**, and the distribution of it. Simply put, the more mass, the more stable and resistant to vibrations the tripod is. Closely related question: [How to stabilize a tripod?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94720/how-to-stabilize-a-tripod)

But even adding lots of mass via hang bags, sandbags, etc., to an undersized tripod won't overcome the limitations of a tripod and head combination that just isn't up to the task.

> I have heard that a heavy tripod is advisable in this context, is that correct and if so how heavy is heavy?

Yes. Caveat: I wouldn't necessarily place the tripod's weight as the *primary* metric to consider for a sturdy tripod. For instance, a heavy duty (and very expensive) carbon fiber tripod such as the [Gitzo Systematic series](https://www.manfrotto.us/gitzo/tripods/systematic) or [Really Right Stuff Versa Series 3 and 4](http://www.reallyrightstuff.com/tripods/carbon-fiber) at just shy of 3 kg is lighter than the largest big-box retailer video tripods, and probably more stable — at easily 5x the cost.

Overall size, and sturdiness of construction (solid leg locks, whether or not there's a center column, sturdiness of the head) and technique (only extending the legs as much as necessary; extending the fatter leg sections rather than skinny tubes when not at full extension; keeping the center column low; etc.) will do more to stabilize a tripod than simple mass alone.

> Looking around the web I found the [Genesis A3](http://www.genesisgear.pl/en/kits/75-genesis-a3-kit-en) tripod that looked promising, am I on the right track with this?

For long-focal length photography, I'd say that tripod is undersized. However, knowing that your focal length is coming from a 3x teleconverter and/or a catadioptric (mirror) lens (which are incredibly light for their focal length) rather than big expensive glass, it could probably be serviceable. As I mentioned before, technique goes a long way. For instance, extending as few legs as possible, and removing the center column to mount the included head directly to the tripod as shown in one of their product photos will provide a fairly sturdy base. Granted, you would be restricted to shooting from a low position, but it would be sturdier than at full extension.

IMO, with that tripod, I think the biggest issue you'll be working against is the ballhead that comes with it. I don't think the ballhead is large enough or sturdy enough for big-glass long focal-length photography. Fortunately, you can always choose to just get a larger ballhead later, or as Xiota suggests, a gimbal head.

See: [What tripod heads are ideal to mount a large telephoto or supertelephoto lens on a tripod?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30640/what-tripod-heads-are-ideal-to-mount-a-large-telephoto-or-supertelephoto-lens-on)

Answer (score 2):

**Consider using a gimbal head** to balance out the weight of the lens and camera.  Long telephoto lenses tend to be unbalanced.  No matter how sturdy the tripod, the tiniest bit of force is leveraged and magnified so that the lens and camera shake independently of the tripod.

To evaluate whether camera shake is at fault, just set your camera down on a sturdy table, and release the shutter via timer.  If pictures are still fuzzy, the problem may be the quality of the teleconverter, as [Phillip Kendall suggests](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103829#comment197042_103829).

Comment: Will this work regardless of tripod or are there some special features of the tripod that are recomended for this?

Comment: I'd think as long as the tripod can support the weight and has the right attachments, it should work fine.  There's a YouTube video about [using a gimbal head on a monopod](https://youtu.be/6wbQgQKqglc).